# Odd behavior with Ruby arrays?

Tags: ruby

I am using Ruby 2.3.1 and I cannot tell if I've encountered a bug or if this is intended behavior.

If you create an NxN matrix by making nested arrays, as such:

```
matrix = [[0]*5]*5
```

and then set the elements on the diagonals, as such:

```
(0..4).each {|i| matrix[i][i] = i}
```

this ends up affecting every column in every row:

```
[
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
]
```

Is this intended behavior?

P.S. I do not want to use Ruby's Matrix library, but would rather work with plain arrays.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So it seems the right way to do it is as follows: `Array.new(n) { Array.new(n, 0)}` but not entirely sure about the details

Comment: "I found a bug in the compiler/interpreter/whatever" - this is false pretty much always :)

Comment: @Sergio, that's because they're usually hardware errors.

Comment: Yes, this is intended behavior. It also gets asked pretty much every other month here on [so]. It is also well-documented in the documentation of `Array#*`. Hint: if you think you have discovered a bug in a piece of code that is used by hundreds of thousands of programmers every day, and you just so happen to be the first person in the history of Ruby to use `Array#*` … you're probably wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby, arrays are, behind the scenes, objects of type `array`, which can contain primitive types and references to other objects. Now, this last bit is important - the array doesn't contain the object itself, but instead a pointer to it, which is interpreted as necessary when the programmer asks for it.

So the OP's original initialization code

```
matrix = [[0]*5]*5
```

Really creates a single `array` object containing 5 0s, and then copies the pointer to it 5 times. This also happens when you do

```
matrix = Array.new(5, Array.new(5, 0))
```

for precisely the same reason. So, as posted in the comments, the idiomatically correct Ruby way to create an array of 5 different `array` objects is

```
matrix = Array.new(5){Array.new(5, 0)}
```

Which yields a single array that contains pointers to 5 *different* `array` objects, preventing the issue encountered by the OP. Full documentation on the behaviour of Ruby arrays can be found at this [finely-crafted link](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the diagonal to observe that behaviour; just change any element, say

```
matrix[1][1] = 1
```

Then

```
matrix
  #=> [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Consider

```
matrix.map { |row| row.object_id }
  #=> [70153694327100, 70153694327100, 70153694327100,
  #    70153694327100, 70153694327100].
```

This shows that all elements ("rows") of `matrix` are the same object, ergo, if that object is changed, all elements of `matrix` are affected. `matrix = [[0]*5]*5` is equivalent to

```
matrix = Array.new(5, Array.new(5,0))
```

(See [Array::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-c-new), expecially "Common gotchas".) What you want (as @Sebastian notes) is

```
matrix = Array.new(5) { Array.new(5,0) }
  #=> [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

so that

```
matrix[1][1] = 1
```

only affects that one element:

```
matrix
  #=> [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
matrix = [[0]*5]*5
```

Let's break this down:

```
a = [0]*5
```

Create an array of 5 zeros; this is an array of integers.

```
matrix = [a] * 5
```

Create an array of 5 *references* to the same array `a`.

So of course when you modify one, the others will be modified; it's the same array.

I don't know Ruby, so please feel free to correct any incorrect terminology.

Comment: Yep this seems right. The odd thing is that it happens both with `[[0]*5]*5` and `Array.new(5, Array.new(5, 0))` where I'd expect two distinct arrays, but actually they reference the same object. The correct way seems to pass a block, as such: `Array.new(n) { Array.new(n, 0)}`